# How to read the first letters in txt.file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I am to read a file in Java that contains the following:

```
.- ... ... .. --. -. -- . -. - ....-
.. ...
..-. .. -. .- .-.. .-.. -.--
-.. --- -. .
```

The thing is it is reading the whole file except the first two characters from the first line and only prints:

**... ... .. --. -. -- . -. - ....-**

instead of

**.- ... ... .. --. -. -- . -. - ....-**

**How can I read the first character of this txt file?**

Here is  the code:

```
String line = "";
String []split;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.print("Input file:");
String inputFile = scanner.nextLine();
File file = new File(inputFile);
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

String [] alphabet = {

  "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"
  ,"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

String [] morse    = {
  ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--",
  "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..",
  "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----."};

 if(input.hasNext())
  input.next();

while(input.hasNextLine()){
  line = input.nextLine();
  split = line.split("\t");


  System.out.println(split[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){

  }  
}
```

}
}

Comment: `if(input.hasNext()) input.next();` why are you doing this? It reads the first string which is ".-" .

Comment: Oh rookie mistake. thats not suppose to be there.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`if(input.hasNext()) input.next();` why are you doing this? It reads the first string which is ".-" . You are reading the string but not assigning it to any variable.

Simply delete this part of the code and this string will be read in the while loop.